# How to fix the "Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'" error in spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am new to spring Hibernate doing the first project and got stuck with the following error. Why is the following error is coming? Tried to search the error but could not resolve.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/bytebuddy/NamingStrategy$SuffixingRandom$BaseNameResolver
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.buildBytecodeProvider(Environment.java:345)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.buildBytecodeProvider(Environment.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.reset(Configuration.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:130)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.<init>(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:158)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.bytebuddy.NamingStrategy$SuffixingRandom$BaseNameResolver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 35 more
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [Github Bytebuddy repo](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/blob/master/byte-buddy-dep/src/main/java/net/bytebuddy/NamingStrategy.java#L209) the `BaseNameResolver` is an interface in `NamingStrategy`.

Most probably you do not have this dependency on your classpath:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
    <artifactId>byte-buddy-dep</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.12</version>
</dependency>
```